# Access Docker socket within container

Tags: docker

I am attempting to create a container that can access the host docker remote API via the docker socket file (host machine - /var/run/docker.sock).

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20985379/1882232) suggests proxying requests to the socket.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 39):

If one intends to use Docker from within a container, they should clearly understand security implications.

Accessing Docker from within the container is simple:

1. Use the `docker` official image or install Docker inside the container. Or you may download archive with docker client binary as described  [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/using-docker-in-a-dockerized-jenkins-container/322/11)
2. Expose Docker unix socket from host to container

That's why

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
       -ti docker
```

should do the trick.

Alternatively, you may expose into container and use  [Docker REST API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/latest/)

UPD: Former version of this answer (based on previous version of  [jpetazzo post](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)  ) advised to bind-mount the docker binary from the host to the container. This is not reliable anymore, because the Docker Engine is no longer distributed as (almost) static libraries.

## Considerations:

1. All host containers will be accessible to container, so it can stop them, delete, *run any commands as any user* inside top-level Docker containers.
2. All created containers are created in a top-level Docker.
3. **Of course, you should understand that if container has access to host's Docker daemon, it has a privileged access to entire host system. Depending on container and system (AppArmor) configuration, it may be less or more dangerous**
4. Other warnings here [dont-expose-the-docker-socket](https://www.lvh.io/posts/dont-expose-the-docker-socket-not-even-to-a-container.html)

Other approaches like exposing `/var/lib/docker` to container are likely to cause data corruption. See [do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)  for more details.

## Note for users of official Jenkins CI container

In this container (and probably in many other) jenkins process runs as a non-root user. That's why it has no permission to interact with docker socket. So quick & dirty solution is running

```
docker exec -u root ${NAME} /bin/chmod -v a+s $(which docker)
```

after starting container. That allows all users in container to run docker binary with root permissions. Better approach would be to allow running docker binary via passwordless sudo, but official Jenkins CI image seems to lack the sudo subsystem.

Comment: Also, there is a great advanced article: http://jpetazzo.github.io/2016/04/03/one-container-to-rule-them-all/

Comment: Mounting the docker binary is [discouraged](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/#the-solution): `Former versions of this post advised to bind-mount the docker binary from the host to the container. This is not reliable anymore, because the Docker Engine is no longer distributed as (almost) static libraries.`

Comment: Thanks for the chmod, that certainly helped!

Answer (score 32):

I figured it out.  You can simply pass the the socket file through the volume argument

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/container/path/docker.sock
```

As @zarathustra points out, this may not be the greatest idea however.  See: https://www.lvh.io/posts/dont-expose-the-docker-socket-not-even-to-a-container/

Comment: You should never do this, see https://www.lvh.io/posts/dont-expose-the-docker-socket-not-even-to-a-container.html

Comment: @Zarathustra agreed and thanks. The question however, was not whether or not it should be done.  I will update the answer here with warning.

Comment: this is how Portainer does it

Comment: So what's the alternative?

Comment: @DesmondMorris it seems that the link is dead. Do you have an updated version?

Comment: @Lucas https://www.lvh.io/posts/dont-expose-the-docker-socket-not-even-to-a-container/

Answer (score 10):

I stumbled across this page while trying to make docker socket calls work from a container that is running as the `nobody` user.

In my case I was getting access denied errors when `my-service` would try to make calls to the docker socket to list available containers.

I ended up using [docker-socket-proxy](https://github.com/Tecnativa/docker-socket-proxy) to proxy the docker socket to `my-service`. This is a different approach to accessing the docker socket within a container so I though I would share it.

I made `my-service` able to receive the docker host it should talk to, `docker-socker-proxy` in this case, via the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable.

Note that `docker-socket-proxy` will need to run as the `root` user to be able to proxy the docker socket to `my-service`.

Example `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  my-service:
    image: my-service
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker-socket-proxy:2375
    networks:
      - my-service_my-network
  docker-socket-proxy:
    image: tecnativa/docker-socket-proxy
    environment:
      - SERVICES=1
      - TASKS=1
      - NETWORKS=1
      - NODES=1
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - my-service_my-network
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: overlay
```

Note that the above compose file is swarm ready (`docker stack deploy my-service`) but it should work in compose mode as well (`docker-compose up -d`). The nice thing about this approach is that `my-service` does not need to run on a swarm manager anymore.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why your network is called `my-network` but your services refer to it as `my-service_my-network`?