# How to safely get rw right to docker.sock from the container?

Tags: php, linux, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-php with nginx + php-fpm (docker-compose project). When I'm trying to run an example from the [documentation](http://docker-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/container-run/):

```
<?php
use Docker\API\Model\ContainersCreatePostBody;
use Docker\Docker;
$docker= Docker::create();
$containerConfig = new ContainersCreatePostBody();
$containerConfig->setImage('nginx:latest');
$containerConfig->setCmd(['echo', 'I am running a command']);
$containerCreateResult = $docker->containerCreate($containerConfig);
var_dump($containerCreateResult);
exit;
```

and I'm getting the error:

```
Http \ Client \ Socket \ Exception \ ConnectionException - Permission denied
```

As far as I understand the problem is that user group, that php-fpm is using, does not have rw rights to docker.sock (I'm mounting it from the host on which the docker is running).

### Configuration:

**docker-compose:**

The shell directory contains an application on yii2, that is used by docker-php.

```
version: '2'
services:
web:
  image: 'nginx:latest'
  container_name: web
  ports:
    - '80:80'
    - '443:443'
  volumes:
    - './:/shell'
  networks:
    - backend
    - frontend
  restart: always
php:
  build: ./docker/php/
  container_name: php
  volumes:
    - './:/shell'
    - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
  environment: []
  networks:
    - backend
  restart: always
networks:
frontend:
  driver: bridge
backend:
  driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile for php-fpm: [github gist](https://gist.github.com/dmitr1y/23634d143cad728d8eccb451651792ff) (too large file for post ~100 lines)

Docker is installed for the experiment, and so it is useless in the container php-fpm.

**Software versions:**

- Docker version 1.13.1
- docker-compose version 1.8.0
- Kubuntu 17.10 x64

I found something similar in the Internet ([one](https://github.com/docker-php/docker-php/issues/222), [two](https://github.com/docker-php/docker-php/issues/239), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135897/access-docker-socket-within-container) ...), the decision is to add the user, from which the application works in the container, to the group www-data.

If I assign 777 rights to docker.sock, then everything will be working, but this is a bad solution =)