# Running docker command in a Java application executing in a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am creating a Spring Boot monitoring agent that collects docker metrics. The agent can be attached through POM dependency to any client Spring Boot application that runs inside a docker container.

In the agent, I am trying to programatically run  `docker stats`

But, it fails to execute because the docker container doesn't have docker client installed in it.

So how can I run docker commands in docker container? Please note, I can't make changes to the `Dockerfile` of client.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Docker socket within container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135897/access-docker-socket-within-container)

Comment: Are you trying to run multiple commands inside the docker container?

Answer (score 0):

You may execute docker commands within the container by defining the docker socket in the container.

run the container and mount the 'docker.sock' in the following manner:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

so mainly you have to mount `docker.sock` to order to run docker commands within container.