# howto check commandlines from docker run commands?

Tags: docker

How can i get the full docker run commandline within the container?

I need this for protocols.

eg

```
docker run -d -e foo=bar -v $PWD:/app image

docker exec -it container bash
# get commandline ??
```

many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by command line? can you explain a bit

Comment: its not really difficult to understand - i need the commandline "docker run -d -e foo=bar -v $PWD:/app image" WITHIN the container

Comment: Okay I got it.. you want to run "docker run " command inside running container, right?

Comment: Why do you need this; what would you do with this information if you had it?

Answer (score 0):

`docker` itself does not offer a straight-forward way to get the actual command which started a container. But you can `docker inspect` the container and reconstruct the command which started it from that.

There are some tools trying to automate this such as [`runlike`](https://github.com/lavie/runlike/#readme), [`rekcod`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rekcod) or this [template for `docker inspect`](https://gist.github.com/efrecon/8ce9c75d518b6eb863f667442d7bc679), see [How to show the run command of a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758793/how-to-show-the-run-command-of-a-docker-container) for more in this.

If you want to get this information *inside* a running container you'll have to mount the `docker` socket into it to be able to use these tools inside the container, see [Access Docker socket within container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135897/access-docker-socket-within-container).